# Is there a way to convert an Access token to Base64 encoded string in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, http, azure-devops

In C#, I have the following code,

```
var personalaccesstoken = "somestring";

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
    Convert.ToBase64String(
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));
```

I would like to convert this code into Angular,
so far I have tried with the following,

```
var config = { headers: {
                        'Authorization': 'Basic token',
                        'Accept': 'application/json'
                    }
                };
var response = $http.get("https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/VerifyServer/_apis/git/repositories/VerifyServer/items?api-version=1.0&scopePath=/src&recursionLevel=Full&includeContentMetadata=true&api-version=1.0", config);
```

But, I am getting redirected to sign in page in the response.
Can anyone help in converting the request to Angular?

Comment: What is "account" supposed to be in your url? If you're expecting that to be a variable that will resolve within the curly braces, it will not. You will have to change the url into either string concatenation or template strings.

ex: ` `https://${account}.visual....` `

Comment: Oh, I just removed the account name for the sake of the question. I do use my actual account name in the code.

Comment: How are you passing your personalaccesstoken to the get request?

Comment: Through Authorization header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code, it works at my side:

```
 var Base64={_keyStr:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",encode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i,s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=Base64._utf8_encode(e);while(f<e.length){n=e.charCodeAt(f++);r=e.charCodeAt(f++);i=e.charCodeAt(f++);s=n>>2;o=(n&3)<<4|r>>4;u=(r&15)<<2|i>>6;a=i&63;if(isNaN(r)){u=a=64}else if(isNaN(i)){a=64}t=t+this._keyStr.charAt(s)+this._keyStr.charAt(o)+this._keyStr.charAt(u)+this._keyStr.charAt(a)}return t},decode:function(e){var t="";var n,r,i;var s,o,u,a;var f=0;e=e.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+/=]/g,"");while(f<e.length){s=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));o=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));u=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));a=this._keyStr.indexOf(e.charAt(f++));n=s<<2|o>>4;r=(o&15)<<4|u>>2;i=(u&3)<<6|a;t=t+String.fromCharCode(n);if(u!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(r)}if(a!=64){t=t+String.fromCharCode(i)}}t=Base64._utf8_decode(t);return t},_utf8_encode:function(e){e=e.replace(/rn/g,"n");var t="";for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r)}else if(r>127&&r<2048){t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6|192);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}else{t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>12|224);t+=String.fromCharCode(r>>6&63|128);t+=String.fromCharCode(r&63|128)}}return t},_utf8_decode:function(e){var t="";var n=0;var r=c1=c2=0;while(n<e.length){r=e.charCodeAt(n);if(r<128){t+=String.fromCharCode(r);n++}else if(r>191&&r<224){c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&31)<<6|c2&63);n+=2}else{c2=e.charCodeAt(n+1);c3=e.charCodeAt(n+2);t+=String.fromCharCode((r&15)<<12|(c2&63)<<6|c3&63);n+=3}}return t}}
 var bstringauth = Base64.encode('anystring:token');
```

Refer to this link for details: [How to Encode and Decode Strings with Base64 in JavaScript](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**vsts-node-api**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api) with authentication in your AngularJs project.

First, plesase install the library by:

```
npm install vso-node-api --save
```

Then create the connect to VSTS as below:

```
import * as vsts from 'vso-node-api';

// your collection url
let collectionUrl = "https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection";

// ideally from config
let token: string = "cbdeb34vzyuk5l4gxc4qfczn3lko3avfkfqyb47etahq6axpcqha"; 

let authHandler = vsts.getPersonalAccessTokenHandler(token); 
let connection = new vsts.WebApi(collectionUrl, authHandler);
```

More details, you can refer [Visual Studio Team Services Client for Node.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/blob/master/README.md#visual-studio-team-services-client-for-nodejs).